# How to assign a drop down selected value to an input field which is present in next td?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a table, I have two columns and many rows. One column have drop down and other have input field of type number. When I change the value of drop down I want to assign that selected value to the input field which is present in next `td`. I hope I explained my problem okay.

Here is what I have tried,

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select.nameSelect').change(function() {
    var id = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
    $(this).closest('.tr').find('.StudentId').val(id);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select name="StudentName" id="StudentName" class="nameSelect">
        <option value="1">Student1</option>
        <option value="2">Student2</option>
        <option value="3">Student3</option>
        <option value="4">Student4</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" class="StudentId" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select name="StudentName" id="StudentName" class="nameSelect">
        <option value="1">Student1</option>
        <option value="2">Student2</option>
        <option value="3">Student3</option>
        <option value="4">Student4</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" class="StudentId" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select name="StudentName" id="StudentName" class="nameSelect">
        <option value="1">Student1</option>
        <option value="2">Student2</option>
        <option value="3">Student3</option>
        <option value="4">Student4</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" class="StudentId" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Note that IDs must be unique to the document. It appears as though your code should work (assuming there are no syntax errors in the console)

Comment: This is just a typo; change `.closest('.tr')` to `.closest('tr')`

Comment: Small point: `$(this).children("option:selected").val()` could be replaced with `$(this).val()` - a `select` automatically takes on the value of the currently selected `option`. And you ought not to keep repeating `id="StudentName"` in multiple dropdowns. IDs are supposed to be unique...otherwise what's the point of them?

Comment: @ADyson - even that appears OTT, when `this.value` will do the same

Comment: @freefaller well yes, I was just sticking to jQuery syntax for consistency, but I agree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, your HTML is invalid due to having multiple elements with the same `id` (`id="StudentName"`).

But the reason your code isn't working is because you're doing `closest('.tr')` when it should be `closest('tr')` because it's an element, not a class.

Also, there is no need to find the selected value... just use `this.value`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select.nameSelect').change(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.StudentId').val(this.value);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select name="StudentName" id="StudentName" class="nameSelect">
        <option value="1">Student1</option>
        <option value="2">Student2</option>
        <option value="3">Student3</option>
        <option value="4">Student4</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" class="StudentId" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select name="StudentName" id="StudentName" class="nameSelect">
        <option value="1">Student1</option>
        <option value="2">Student2</option>
        <option value="3">Student3</option>
        <option value="4">Student4</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" class="StudentId" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select name="StudentName" id="StudentName" class="nameSelect">
        <option value="1">Student1</option>
        <option value="2">Student2</option>
        <option value="3">Student3</option>
        <option value="4">Student4</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" class="StudentId" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you @freefaller. It worked for me. That same id's was a copy paste mistake.